# in SML, how to write 'map' with NumPy-like broadcasting for multi-dimensional arrays?

Tags: dictionary, multidimensional-array, numpy, sml

[Here](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) are the full rules, but as a quick example, if `A` is a 3D array with type `'a list list list` and `f` a function with type `'a list -> 'b`, I would like a function `map'` that takes lifts `f` to type `'a list list list -> 'b list list`.  For the specific example, `map'` would be equivalent to this code:

```
fun map' fList aListListList = map (fn aListList => map fList aListList) A
```

Except, of course, I would like this `map'` to work regardless of how many dimensions `A` had.  I'm having trouble writing the type signature, which is often a sign that I'm doing it wrong.

**edit**: How's this as a workaround?

```
fun map' levels f A = 
  if levels < 1
  then return f(A)
  else return map' (levels - 1) f A
```

Answer (score 1):

You're having problems coming up with the right type, because the right type for this function can't be expressed in SML's type system. You can't abstract over a nested list's nesting depth like this. The function you want can simply not be expressed in SML.

The only thing you can do is define your own type for nested lists and then write a function `map' : ('a list -> 'b) -> 'a nestedlist -> 'b nestedlist`. However as you can see the nesting depth of a `nestedlist` would not be encoded in its type, nor would the fact that `map'` strips exactly one level of nesting visible from its type (or verified by the compiler).

Comment: Ah, I suspected but wasn't sure.  What do you think of asking the user to specify how many levels down he wants to recurse?  It's a little less convenient, and still breaks the type-check, but at least it would produce correct output.  Or is there a better way to get the desired behavior?

Comment: @Wang: Letting the user specify the depth seems fine, but you still need the custom data type. Also note that the code you posted in your edit won't work because a) there is no return keyword in sml and b) you're only calling f once and not building a list at all.